# Not able to get Socket Message to ejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, ejs

I'm trying to pass the message from Node JS to Front end using socket. But, the message does not get transmitted.

```
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
   io.emit('order', "Order Updated");
   console.log("Order Updated");
}); 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'));

http.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + PORT);
});
```

The console log is getting printed as `Order Updated`. In the index.ejs file I have the following code and I do not see any console log in the UI.

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('order', function(msg){
      console.log(msg);
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Update 1**

Based on the following answers, I updated the code to :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('order', "Order Updated");
});
```

**Update 2**

```
$(function () {
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000', {transports ['polling']});
   socket.on('order', function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
   });
});
```

Image of Server side console log :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe on your server side, you have to emit to your connected socket like this ?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.emit('order', "Order Updated");
   console.log("Order Updated");
});
```

**EDIT**

On my client side, I'm connecting with host:port like this, and it works properly

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000', {transports: ['polling']});
socket.on('order', function(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

On my index.html (client side), I'm also calling socket.io like this :

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- directly get from Node.js server -->
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did update, still I do not see any data being passed to the UI. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe you should try to connect with full host:port like on my edit ?

Comment: I did try that too, still no luck.

Comment: And your server side log "Order Updated" is displayed each time you refresh your client browser ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Attached the image.

Comment: Good to know ! :)

Comment: Your Edit 2 was a saviour. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should emit only to the connected socket:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('order', 'Order Updated');
});
```

Otherwise you are emitting to all of the connected clients, which is probably not what you want.

EDIT:
You have to specify the port on which you are connecting in your socket.io instatiation code:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
```

It's also adviseable to store the URL and the port in variables, so that you can configure them easily when deploying to production environments.

Comment: I did update, still I do not see any data being passed to the UI. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: You need to share the code for the server-side socket.io configuration. Maybe you aren't connecting to the server at all.

Comment: I updated the code, I'm basically running in PORT 5000.